# Access a remote service limited with one connection with a RoR application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I have a Ruby on Rails application, and I need to access a remote service to consult/modify some data.
I can't open more than one session to this service, but my application needs more than one unicorn worker to run.
I've tried to create an Object with

```
include Singleton
```

but this only limits one session per worker.
How can I for this limitation?
Do I have to create a separated application with only one worker?
Thanks

Comment: you can create a lock in Rails.cache or your DB

Comment: share more of your code for specific help

Comment: Sounds like an application for a background worker. Check out Sidekiq and consider having a local version of the data you need as a cache.